# Dynamic method names

Tags: php

I would like to call a method dynamically. Since I have many methods, which start with `set`, the rest of the method name should be dynamic.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$column = 'City';

function setCity() {
    echo 'London';
}

set${column}();
```

I get the error message:

> syntax error, unexpected '$'

Comment: You could also do this `$func = "set{$column}"; $func();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the function name before calling the function...

```
$func = "set{$column}";
$func();
```

Comment: Thank you but what if my method needs to be called like this: `$country->setCity();` ?

Comment: You should be able to do `$country->$func();`

Comment: Wow that's great! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

[call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) will achieve this.

```php
$column = 'City';

function setCity() {
    echo 'London';
}

call_user_func("set$column"); // London
```